# laravel 5.2 cannot sent large string via ajax and get method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

i try to send a parameter with url to server with ajax in laravel 5.2 but when the length of url become more than 5000 char i face the error that Http not found in route
here is my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/uploadQuestionMod5/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN , jcategory2:jcategory2 , jquestionText:jquestionText , jkind:jkind},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

and my controller is :

```
$jcategory2 = $request['jcategory2'];
$jquestionText = $request['jquestionText'];
$jkind = $request['jkind'];

$category2 = json_decode($jcategory2);
$questionText = json_decode($jquestionText);
$kind = json_decode($jkind);

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$insertquestion = DB::table('questionsInfo')->insert(
    ['userId' => $userId ,'categoryId' => $category2 ,'questionKind' => $kind ,'questionText' => $questionText , 'questionFileUrl' => null ,'date' => $now]
);
```

i try to find the limit of url size in get method please help me thank you :)

Comment: change your method from GET to POST. And accept POST method from server (Route to support post method) and make POST call via ajax. `type: 'GET'` is not capable of large input.

Comment: i used that but i saw MethodNotAllowedHttpException error , i change the method to post in route adn handle token_miss_match but still has error

Comment: Yeah thats why i said change your route so that your route can support post method. `/uploadQuestionMod5/` this is your route. I will post code for you

Comment: for token mismatch refresh the page and make ajax call again.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Easy Solution try would be using AJAX POST not GET method. 
Make your AJAX post and change your route (/uploadQuestionMod5/) in route file **`(/App/Http/routes.php)`** as

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/uploadQuestionMod5', [
    'uses'=>'YourController@method'
]);
```

**Note**: this route will accept both `get` and `post` ajax request.

If you only do post ajax then your route looks like:

```
Route::post('/uploadQuestionMod5', 'YourController@method');
```

This route will accept `post` request comming from ajax call or any toher source (Client)

**Update:** Token Mismatch Error means following
 1. You have missed to submit CSRF tokens fields via AJAX post.
 2. Tokens might have changed but you did not have refreshed your page, just making ajax request again and again.

 It seems you are submitting your `CSRF_TOKEN` correctly, so refresh the page and try again to make ajax call.